# VS Code's launch.json keeps reseting after debugging

Tags: debugging, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I'm using VS Code's debugger to debug my Unity3D project.  Every time I start debugger message appears that read

> Please add an attribute "request": "attach" to your configuration.

I press configuration button (with cogwheel icon), it opens "launch.json" file in text editor, then I'm adding "request": "attach" line to the configuration, starting debugger - everything works fine. But after I stop debugger and try to start it again, I have to do same stuff again, because line "request": "attach" disappeared for some reason.

Does anyone know how to make VS Code not reset configuration file?

Comment: Did you follow this official setup guide? https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/runtimes/unity

Comment: @user3071284 yeah, thats what I did in the first place

Comment: I went through the guide and ended up using the asset store version mentioned. I ended up going back to MonoDevelop-Unity, because the integration wasn't as smooth. I was on a Mac.